# Run my Macro when excel cell changes

Tags: vba, excel, email, automation

I am looking to have my spreadsheet send emails once a cell changes.

Thus far I have a macro to send to a group of emails and a command button macro to trigger this, but would like it to happen automatically when a cell changes state.

Now I have:

```
Sub Create_Email_From_Excel()
    Dim SendTo As String
    Dim ToMSg As String

For i = 1 To 10
    SendTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    If SendTo <> “” Then
        ToMSg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Send_Mail_From_Excel SendTo, ToMSg
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Sub Send_Mail_From_Excel(SendTo As String, ToMSg As String)
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutlookMail
    .To = SendTo
    .CC = "john@interwebs.com"
    .BCC = “”
    .Subject = "You have mail"
    .Body = "this is your mail"
    .Send
End With
```

And...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click
  Create_Email_From_Excel
End Sub
```

I'm not sure where to go from here or if I'm going in the right direction. The command button and macros work but I am at a loss to go any further.

If it could excecute the create email from excel macro when a cell in column G changes from "pending" to "Late" that would be outstanding.

Comment: Have a look at the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

Try Worksheet_Change event

Example

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$G$1" Then
        '
        'When someone Edits the cell G1
        '
        Call Create_Email_From_Excel
        '
        '
    End If
End Sub
```